# What part of the 2-adic space is projected down to the odd numbers by the equivalence relation $x\sim \frac{x}{2}$?

Tags: equivalence-relations, p-adic-number-theory

> What part of the 2-adic space is, and isn't, projected down to the odd numbers by the equivalence relation $x\sim \frac{x}{2}$?

If we define $\mathbb{N}/\sim$ as the partitioning of $\{x\in\mathbb{N_{>0}}\}$ by the equivalence relation $x\sim\frac{x}{2}$, then this effectively projects $\mathbb{N}$ down to the odd numbers.

In fact going further it also projects every fraction $\left\{\frac{2n+1}{2^m}:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$ down to an odd number.

All these numbers; am I right in thinking these are best described as $\mathbb{Z}_2\cap\mathbb{Q}$ ?

What else do we find in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Q}_2$?

I'm not clear on what for example would be the value of $\lvert\sqrt{2}\rvert_2$; whether we can have non-integer values such as $\lvert\sqrt{2}\rvert_2=\frac{1}{2}$ which would not be in the above set, but would be in:

$\left\{\frac{2n+1}{2^m}:n\in\mathbb{Z},m\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you ask, but I want to make a few comments. A) Nitpick: your $\sim$ is not an equivalence relation. Undoubtedly you want its equivalent closure. B) Yes, over $\Bbb{N}$ the set of odd natural numbers forms a set of representative of equivalence classes. C) Over $\Bbb{Q}_2$ similarly the multiplicative group of 2-adic units $1+2\Bbb{Z}_2$ contains a unique representative from each equivalence class. D) To handle $\sqrt2$ we need to move outside $\Bbb{Q}_2$. You need to describe the extension of $\sim$ more carefully.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry you've totally thrown me with your first comment that $\sim$ isn't an equivalence relation, because I think I don't want its equivalent closure but I don't understand why you would say I do. Are you simply saying I haven't stated its reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity? or are you suggesting the relation as I state it doesn't handle e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ while its equivalent closure would? Or something else?

Comment: Probably the first. You simply didn't state that we also have $x\sim x$, $x/2\sim x$, $x\sim x/4$ et cetera. Equivalent closure takes care of those, and you obviously meant the relation $x\sim y\Leftrightarrow x=2^ny$ for some integer $n$. But, that doesn't help with $\sqrt2$. For all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ we have $2^n\sqrt2\notin\Bbb{Q}_2$.

Comment: 1) How do you define $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Q}_2$ ? 2) Can you define them as rings, and the group of units $\mathbb{Z}_2^\times$ ?  3) $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times \cong p^{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ thus $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times \cong \mathbb{Q}_p^\times / p^{\mathbb{Z}}$ 4) $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})^\times \cong \sqrt{p}^{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt{p}]^\times$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $2$-adic number $x \in \mathbb{Q}_2$ can be uniquely written as

$$x = 2^n u$$

Where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the $2$-adic valuation of $x$ and $u \in 1+2\mathbb{Z}_2$ is an odd $2$-adic integer.

If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a rational number then $u$ is rational, which means that we can write $u=\frac{a}{b}$ with $a$ and $b$ odd.

As for what "happens" to $\sqrt{2}$, or more precisely what are the equivalence classes in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, you can understand it by looking at $\mathbb{Q}_2[\sqrt{2}]$. Here, using Hensel's lemma, any element $x \in \mathbb{Q}_2[\sqrt{2}]$ can be uniquely written

$$x = \sqrt{2}^n u$$

with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $u \in 1+ \sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}_2[\sqrt{2}]$. And when $x\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, then $u$ can be written $u = a + b\sqrt{2}$ with $a$ a rational numbers with odd numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thanks. The implication of your answer is (if $\langle2\rangle=\{\ldots\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},1,2,4,\ldots\}$) that the part projected down to $\mathbb{N}$ is $X=\{\frac{a}{b}:b=1\}\times\langle2\rangle$. Is that correct? Does that set have a better name or description?  So the part not projected down is $\mathbb{Q}_2\setminus X$